# How to upload files to one drive using ssis?

Tags: ssis, onedrive, msbi, kingswaysoft

I am looking for a way to upload files to One Drive using SSIS. I've researched and there are some third party tools like CozyRoc, KingswaySoft which provide one drive connection manager. Anyone out there who already have experience doing this? If so please share!

Comment: Either you need to use a third-party software. Else you need to get the SDK and make a script task where you code yourself out of it. If you dont know how to program in C# i would suggest you buy a third.party software.

Comment: CozyRoc and zappysys provide one drive connectivity. I am kind of more leaned towards using Microsoft connectivity for reliability purposes.I didn't find anything on Microsoft sites regarding one drive connectivity except one drive in Microsoft graph.Its kind of shocking they don't have a way to connect directly from SSIS. Does Microsoft provide some thing else that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a much easier way to do this without the need of any third party software. Download one drive to your local machine and then login.
You can upload, download, delete files.To map the One Drive for Business cloud drive on Windows follow the below steps

Map network location in File Explorer (My Computer)

```
       a. Open File Explorer (or My Computer in older Windows) and select This PC on the left side tree.

       b. Click on Add Network Location button in the ribbon (or right click on empty space in File Explorer and select Add Network Location).
```

[Map network location in File Explorer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nGIA.png)

```
       c. Click Next on Add Network Wizard window

       d. Click to select Choose custom network location and click Next

       e. Copy the URL from the address box and add Documents in the end like below example  

          https://<your Office365 tenant name>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<yourrname>_company_com/Documents
```

[Add Network Wizard window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4bcB.jpg)

```
       f. Enter a name for your network location and click Next and Finish to complete the wizard.
```

[network location name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23T97.jpg)

```
      g. You will find the mapped network location in My PC section.
```

[Mapped Network location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rUV0.jpg)

Use File System Task to upload, create, delete etc.. And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Our [SSIS Productivity Pack](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack) offers [OneDrive Destination component](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/help-manual/cloud-storage/onedrive-destination-component) which supports Create/Update/Delete data from your OneDrive. You can download the toolkit and give it a try, if you run into any problems, please feel free to let us know. We are more than happy to help!